# Поток ввода из строки std::istringstream и его преобразование

Tags: c++, c++11, потоки-данных, fstream

Плохо понимаю как работают потоки в С++ и конкретно как работать с **std::istringstream**.
Выполняю задание, вот его фрагмент:

> В данном задании вам предлагается написать шаблонную функцию
>   `from_string`, которая умеет преобразовывать строку в разные типы. Для
>   реализации `from_string` предлагается воспользоваться классом
>   `std::istringstream`, который представляет собой поток ввода из строки,
>   т.е. для преобразования строки в тип `T` предлагается прочитать значение
>   типа `T` из потока при помощи оператора `>>`. В случае неудачного
>   преобразования функция должна бросать исключение `bad_from_string`,
>   класс которого вам нужно реализовать самостоятельно.

**1**.Как работать с потоками с перегруженным оператором `>>` ?
**2**.Вот пример с [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws):

```
char c1, c2, c3;
std::istringstream("a b c") >> c1 >> c2 >> c3;
std::cout << "Default  behavior: c1 = " << c1 << " c2 = " << c2 << " c3 = " << c3 << '\n';
std::istringstream("a b c") >> std::noskipws >> c1 >> c2 >> c3;
std::cout << "noskipws behavior: c1 = " << c1 << " c2 = " << c2 << " c3 = " << c3 << '\n';
```

Я правильно понимаю, что в строке 1 записываем в поток символы **a,b,c** с **пробелами** между ними и **читаем его игнорируя пробелы**? В строке 3 мы из потока с теми же данными "смещаем" эти же данные в `noskips` и записываем каждый символ включая пробелы?.

**3**.Приведите **краткий** пример (без проверок и прочего) как нужно пользоваться `std::istringstream` в шаблонной функции, такой как эта, чтобы преобразовывать `std::string` в тип `T`:

```
template<class T>
T from_string(std::string const& s)
{

}
```

Comment: Возможно, стоит разделить вопрос на несколько

Comment: @cppquestions вопросы все одной тематики и ответ может уместиться в +-10 строк кода с комментариями. Я убрал один из дублирующих друг друга вопросов.

Comment: Если вы знаете как работает поток ввода std::istream,  его функциональности. то  std::istringstream имеет такие же функциональности, так как является его наследником

Comment: *"Приведите краткий пример"* Не понимаю, а чем пример с cppreference плох? Туда только проверку ошибок добавить: `if (!(std::istringstream(строка) >> объект)) throw что-нибудь;`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да вот как раз начинает в голове что-то складываться :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как должен работать ваш код, вы напишете сами. Я лишь приведу очень простой(наивный) пример:

```
struct bad_from_string {
    static void print(std::ostream& stream)
    {
        stream << "bad_type\n";
    }
};

template<class T>
T from_string(std::string const& s)
{
    std::istringstream is(s);
    T obj;
    if(!(is >> obj))
        throw bad_from_string();
    return obj;
}
int main()
{    
    try {
        std::cout << from_string<float>("5.0") << std::endl
                  << from_string<char>("float") << std::endl;
        std::cout << from_string<float>("float") << std::endl; // thrown
    }
    catch (bad_from_string) {
        bad_from_string::print(std::cout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Точно так же как и с потоками iostream
2. Верно

3.

```
// функция from_string
template<class T>
T from_string(std::string const& s)
{
    try
    {
        T obj;
        if (! (std::istringstream(s) >> std::noskipws >> obj) ) throw ...
        return obj;
        //используем std::istringstream так же как и std::istream
        //т.к. они обладают
        //одинаковой функциональностью.
        //получаем в  std::istringstream(s) строку s
        //которую передали в ф-ю, далее пишем 
        //её внаш объект obj типа T.

    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
         ...    
    }
}
```